# How to open the SnippingTool (Win Tool) passing a parameter to start automatically?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, parameters

I'm trying to open the Windows tool called SnippingTool and look for an option to start a new snip automatically. Something like this:

```
cmd c:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe /new
```

Some ideas?

Comment: There is a AutoHotKey script that you can try. http://www.mrautomaton.com/2015/10/26/automate-snipping-tool-with-autohotkey/

Comment: If you are looking for instant screenshot, use `Windows Key` + `Print Screen` to instantly save the screenshot inside _Pictures/Screenshots_ folder.

Comment: @w32sh works very well, thank you, put your comment as ans, please.

Comment: `SnippingTool.exe /clip` will capture a region to clipboard, so you can paste on any picture editor, as well on Windows 10 Creators Update there is a hotkey `Win+Shift+S`

Answer (score 9):

`/clip` will do the trick.

Create a link and add `C:\Windows\System32\snippingtool.exe /clip`.

Then add it to your task bar.

Every time you click, the selection cross will be shown. After selecting, the selection will be copied to the clip board.

Comment: I know the question was about Windows 10 and was correct at the time, but for some reason this command doesn't seem to work on Windows 11 Home (version 23H2). It just opens the main Snipping Tool window. They seem to have removed the "/clip" command line parameter. What does work in Windows 11 though is the command "`explorer ms-screenclip:`" (without the quotes).